# How to go to a certain URL, when the result of the form is different?

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I'm having a Magento store and I've made a form for people to calculate the power their products need to have, to operate properly for them.

You can find the page over here; http://www.droomkachels.nl/welke-houtkachel-past-bij-mij

When the result is 1, it should go to /url-A and when it's 2 go to /url-B and so on.

Regards

Comment: redirect them there or send the input from the form there?..

Comment: When the form is filled it, they need to click a button and then be redirected to the right URL which belong to their result from the form.

Answer (score 0):

Use a PHP redirect without echoing out anything else.

```
if ($result == 1)
   header('Location: a.php');
else
   header('Location: b.php');
```

Or use a switch for more pages in a cleaner way.

```
switch($result) {

    case 1:
        header('Location: a.php');
        break;

    case 2:
        header('Location: b.php');
        break;

    case 3:
        // another page
        break;
}
```

Comment: Where should I add this in my code? Can't paste my code over here. IF I  delete this part of the code it doesn't work anymore and that is where my URL is described; totvan = Math.floor(totaal);
tottot = totvan + 1;
slink = "/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?kwh%5Bfrom%5D="+totvan+"&kwh%5Bto%5D="+tottot;

top.location = "/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?kwh%5Bfrom%5D="+totvan+"&kwh%5Bto%5D="+tottot;

window.location.href = "/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?kwh%5Bfrom%5D="+totvan+"&kwh%5Bto%5D="+tottot;
window.location = "/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?kwh%5Bfrom%5D="+totvan+"&kwh%5Bto%5D="+tottot;